# How use TextToColumns in Win32com

Tags: win32com

I would like a exemple how to use TextToColumns in Win32com

```html
Sub VBA_Code()
  Columns("A").TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, FieldInfo:=Array(1, xlDMYFormat)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi
Any help?
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own question using code below

```html
xw.Range('A:A').api.TextToColumns()
```

Thanks